# How to vertically center text in textarea?

Tags: text, textarea, center, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

Is there a way to vertically center text entered in textarea with known width and height? I have a fixed-sized textarea where text should be typed in and I want the text to start from the center while you type it. Horizontal centering could be done with text-align:center, but I cant find any way to align horizontally.

Comment: some code please, what you have tried?

Comment: check this out http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/gICqd

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do the vertical alignment directly. You should make another div over the text area and use it to make text vertically aligned and take the inputs from user to the textarea and transfer it to the div using the JS.

And make the textarea invisible only.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a `<textarea />`, but does the job visually:

```js
// you don't need JS, just demo-ing `input` eventListener works:
document.querySelector('.textarea').addEventListener('input', e => {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
})
```

```css
.textarea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: safe center;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 60vh;
  min-height: 4rem;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: monospace;
}
.textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true">
  not exactly a textarea...
</div>
```