# How to vertically center text in textarea with more than one line placeholder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment

So this solution works great...until you have a placeholder text that wraps to more than one line...

[How to vertically center text in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552655/)

demo: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/gICqd

Anyone have suggestions to fix this?

## EDIT

Anyone care to check this: http://www.2plygraphics.com/im-here

this is a live page with this implemented...I can't for the life of me figure out why the placeholder is always NOT centered...until you start typing

Comment: I must be misunderstanding - it looks like it always stays centered vertically.

Comment: works fine for me: EDIT: apparently i cant get this to share.EDIT: [i <3 jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rt3L8/)

Comment: Anyone care to check this: http://2plygraphics.com/im-here/

this is a live page with this implemented...can't for the life of me figure out why it's always NOT centered...until you start typing

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/rt3L8/, it looks like it does, but change the height on #wrap to 20%...see that it's not centered...it centers the first line of the placeholder, not the rest...even making it an odd number of lines like three doesn't help